# Reducing noise on casette recordings

Tags: noise, recording

I found our old casette player and bunch of empty casettes in attic, also they are in excellent situation. I wanted to record a mix tape for nostalgia but there was no aux input, only an old microphone. So, I bought a fm transmitter and tried to record while broadcasting songs. Sound was very good on radio but when I tried to record it, it came with huge background noise. I tried removing microphone and sending sound from mic connections, but it is still noisy. Does anyone have any idea what the source of this sound could be? Can I get rid of it? (Player works fine, my old tapes sound good)

Comment: How does the cassette player work? Does it have its own amplifier and speaker? (Most I remember as having a place to plug in a headphone. Yours doesn't have this? I think it must have as you were able to broadcast it on FM. But perhaps that was done by a microphone pickup from the speaker? If so, there are coil-devices that can directly pick up from the speaker and convey a signal that can be recorded.)

Comment: It have one speaker and mono-aux output. It also records in mono.I did not fully understand what you said about coil. I did research and there are recording devices with dolby noise reduction option but they are expensive and I was wondering if I could build a simple circuit to make it less noisy. Since I am not familiar with the casette system, I dont know if I can add filter circuit to system externally.